# "error: cannot find symbol method" in Android Studio

Tags: android, fragment

I'm learning how to program Android in Android Studio slowly but surely, working on an app to open the mobile Facebook site in a fragment, with the intent to make multiple fragments for multiple social networks. I have my main (Facebook) fragment, but I'm getting this odd error:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class fragment_main extends Fragment {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
  }

public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } 
}
}
```

It keeps wanting to move my "mWebView" to my "private WebView," which gives more, odder errors. Also, apologizes if this is dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your statements like following; you are `return`ing before you have done anything in your `onCreateView()`   method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);//
}
```